Bad Ping and WiFi Performance on Ideapad 5 Pro 14ACN6 w/ Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Adapter
My Laptop (IdeaPad 5 Pro 14ACN6) has since I got it about a year had pretty bad WiFi performance, specifically in ping times compared to all my other devices, I am able to make use of almost all of the bandwidth on my WiFi ~300-400  Mbps but the ping is extremely bad when using remote desktop locally, and playing online games. I seem to get 50-60 ms when all my other devices get ~15-20 ms ping. The driver seems to be the most recent one(v12.0.0.1257), but I am wondering if there are any other things I can mess around with to help improve performance, as for online gaming it isn't great, and for remote desktop(client) it is almost unuseable right now, even using a completely local network for remote desktop.
